# Expire User Session if he is inactive for a certain period of time and record his session start and end time in database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am working on a Django back end application where I need to Record the user activities i.e his login time and his logout time. If he is inactive for more than 30 minutes I want user to logout automatically, expire user's session and store the logout time into a table. For this I wrote a model , user_logged_in and user_logged_out signals and a Middleware class.

#### models.py for storing the information about user session or login and logout time

```
class UserActivities(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User)
login_time=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
logout_time=models.DateTimeField(null=True)
activity_time=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8,decimal_places=2,null=True,default=0)
```

#### user_logged_in signal to store user login time in the table UserActivities and storing its id to the session key

```
def save_login_time(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    try:
        user_activity_id=UserActivities.objects.create(user=request.user,
                                               login_time=request.user.last_login)
        request.session['user_activity_id']=user_activity_id.id
        request.session['last_request']=timezone.now()
    except:
        print " sorry user activity instance couldn't be created"
user_logged_in.connect(save_login_time)
```

#### logout view to logout the user if he simply logout and expire his session and store logout time in table

```
def logout_view(request):
    user_activity_id=request.session['user_activity_id']
    user_activity_instance=UserActivity.objects.get(id=user_activity_id)
    user_activity_instance.logout_time=timezone.now()
    user_activity_instance.activity_time=(timezone.now()-user_activity_instance.login_time).total_seconds()
    user_activity_instance.save()
    logout(request)
    return logout_then_login()
```

if user do logout then this code is fine

 Middleware class to logout user and expire user's session if user is inactive for 30 minutes

```
class UserLogOutMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if 'last_request' in request.session:
            if (timezone.now()-request.session['last_request']).total_seconds()>=30000:
                user_activity=UserActivity.objects.get(id=request.session['user_id'])
                user_activity.logout_time=request.session['last_request']+timedelta(minutes=30)
                logout(request)
            else:
                    request.session['now']=timezone.now()
        return None
```

Using the above code what I am doing is when user is login I assign the current time to

```
request.session['last_request'] and  If the next request comes 
after 30 minutes of first request the user will be logged out or
timezone.now() will be request.session['last_request'].
```

#### I have set

```
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True
```

as given in documents If SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE is set to True, Django will use browser-length cookies – cookies that expire as soon as the user closes his or her browser. Use this if you want people to have to log in every time they open a browser. It will expire user's session.  Can I get this event or the time when user Close browser in django.

and tell me as i did It the right way to accomplish this task. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a variant, you can setup an JS timer function **setInterval(checkLogout, 10000)** and in **checkLogout** function every 10 seconds (the second argument in setInterval function in ms) request any url, which view will be store users' login time, if it will be more than 30 minutes, redirect them to logout page.

Comment: thank you Greg, The thing I wrote is working fine for me. If a request comes after 30 minutes it will logout the user and redirected him / her to login page. Is that not a right way?  and my main problem is to get the event on browser close. I tried to send a request document.close(function(){}) but i want to do this in a pythonic way.